# How to Configure spring kafka to start additional instances of a Kafka producer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a KAFKA producer used in a request/reply configuration. When one instance of the producer is launched, it works perfect. However when launching a second instance of the producer, the seconds instance won't work. It will write the message to the topic correctly, The consumer will process the message and sends the reply back, however the producer will not find the reply message it is waiting  and it times out. It appears that the message is been picked up by the first instance of the producer. Since the first instance is not expecting this reply message. The request/reply message fails. Is there any configuration missing to make the second instance work? This POC is to be used in an Openshift POD so it should be able to scale to multiple producer and multiple consumer instances. The following is my configuration for consumer and producer. Thanks

**Kafka Producer Config**

```
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.request-reply-topic}")
    String requestReplyTopic;

    @Value("${kafka.request-reply.timeout-ms}")
    private Long replyTimeout;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
       // props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
       // props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
        //props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
        //props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, InGetAccountInfo, AccountInquiryDto> replyKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, InGetAccountInfo> pf, KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, AccountInquiryDto> container){
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate(pf, container);

    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, InGetAccountInfo> requestProducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, AccountInquiryDto> replyConsumerFactory() {
        JsonDeserializer<AccountInquiryDto> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
        jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages(InGetAccountInfo.class.getPackage().getName());
        jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages(AccountInquiryDto.class.getPackage().getName());
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),jsonDeserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, AccountInquiryDto> replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, AccountInquiryDto> cf) {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(requestReplyTopic);
        return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
    }



    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin admin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }



    @Bean
    public KafkaAsyncService kafkaAsyncService(){
        return new KafkaAsyncService();
    }


}
```

**Kafka producer class**

```
public AccountInquiryDto getModelResponse(InGetAccountInfo accountInfo) throws Exception{

        LOGGER.info("Received request for request  for account " + accountInfo);

        // create producer record
        ProducerRecord<String, InGetAccountInfo> record = new ProducerRecord<String, InGetAccountInfo>(requestTopic,accountInfo);
        // set reply topic in header
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, requestReplyTopic.getBytes()));

        // post in kafka topic
        RequestReplyFuture<String, InGetAccountInfo, AccountInquiryDto> sendAndReceive = kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);

        // confirm if producer produced successfully
        SendResult<String, InGetAccountInfo> sendResult = sendAndReceive.getSendFuture().get();

       // //print all headers
        sendResult.getProducerRecord().headers().forEach(header -> System.out.println(header.key() + ":" + header.value().toString()));

        // get consumer record
        ConsumerRecord<String, AccountInquiryDto> consumerRecord = sendAndReceive.get();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        AccountInquiryDto modelResponse = mapper.convertValue(
                consumerRecord.value(),
                new TypeReference<AccountInquiryDto>() { });


        LOGGER.info("Returning record for " + modelResponse);

        return modelResponse;

    }
```

**Kafka Consumer Config**

```
public class KafkaConfig {

  @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
  private String bootstrapServers;

  @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
  private String groupId;

  @Value("${kafka.topic.acct-info.request}")
  private String requestTopic;

  @Value("${kafka.topic.request-reply.timeout-ms}")
  private Long replyTimeout;

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, InGetAccountInfo> requestConsumerFactory() {
    JsonDeserializer<InGetAccountInfo> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
    jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages(InGetAccountInfo.class.getPackage().getName());
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),jsonDeserializer);
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, InGetAccountInfo>> requestReplyListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, InGetAccountInfo> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(requestConsumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(3);
    factory.setReplyTemplate(replyTemplate());
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, AccountInquiryDto> replyProducerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, AccountInquiryDto> replyTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(replyProducerFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public DepAcctInqConsumerController Controller() {
    return new DepAcctInqConsumerController();
  }
  @Bean

  public KafkaAdmin admin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
  }

  @Bean
  public NewTopic requestTopic() {
    Map<String, String> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put("retention.ms", replyTimeout.toString());
    return new NewTopic(requestTopic, 2, (short) 2).configs(configs);
  }


}
```

**Kafka Consumer class**

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.acct-info.request}", containerFactory = "requestReplyListenerContainerFactory")
  @SendTo
  public Message<?> listenPartition0(InGetAccountInfo accountInfo,
                                     @Header(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC) byte[] replyTo,
                                     @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int id) {

    try {

      LOGGER.info("Received request for partition id = " +  id);
      LOGGER.info("Received request for accountInfo = " +  accountInfo.getAccountNumber());

      AccountInquiryDto accountInfoDto  = getAccountInquiryDto(accountInfo);

      LOGGER.info("Returning accountInfoDto = " +  accountInfoDto.toString());

      return MessageBuilder.withPayload(accountInfoDto)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, replyTo)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, id)
              .build();


    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.toString(),e);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by modifying the configuration for the producer adding a variable CLIENT_ID_CONFIG with the following:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId +  "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG,"2");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

    return props;
}
```